# LWC Quick Action Not Reopening after getting closed

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-quickaction

I have created a quick action to open a lwc page, and I have used slds-modal instead lightning-quick-action-panel, for a better look and feel. And then I have used CloseScreenEvent when the close on the modal is clicked

THe quick action opens fine, and closes fine as well. However, when I again click the quick action button on the highlights panel it doesn't open.

I have tried to using renderedCallback, but it then does not close, could anyone help on how to solve this.

Putting my code:

LWC:

```
      <template if:true={showPdfPopupQuickAction}>
     <div style="height:1240px">
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-02" aria-modal="true"
           aria-describedby="modal-content-id-2" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large">
           <div class="slds-modal__container ">
              <header class="slds-modal__header">
                 <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={closePdfPopup}>
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="action:close" alternative-text="Close" size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                 </button>
                 <h2 id="modal-heading-02" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">{eopDocumentHeader}
                 </h2>
              </header>
              <template if:true={showEopError}>
                 <div class="slds-modal__content slds-theme_default slds-scrollable_y" id="modal-content-id-2">
                    <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-alert_warning" role="alert">
                       <span class="slds-assistive-text">warning</span>
                       <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-warning slds-m-right_x-small" title="Description of icon when needed">
                          <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
                             <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#warning"></use>
                          </svg>
                       </span>
                       <h2>{eopErrorMessage}
                       </h2>
                       <div class="slds-notify__close">
                          <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-small" title="Close">
                             <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
                             </svg>
                             <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                          </button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </template>
              <template if:false={showEopError}>
                 <div class="slds-modal__content slds-theme_default modalBody" id="modal-content-id-3">
                    <iframe id="pdfFramePopupNew" height="1200px" src={sourceUrlStaticResource}
                       onload={loadPdfModal} class="pdfFrame"></iframe>
                 </div>
              </template>
              <!-- <iframe id="pdfFramePopup" height="500px" width="1050px" src="/resource/lcins1_pdfjs/web/viewer.html" onload={loadPdfModal} class="pdfFrame"></iframe> -->
           </div>
           <!-- <footer class="slds-modal__footer slds-theme_shade">
              <a filename="custom_filename.pdf" href="{! 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+ v.pdfData}">Download PDF (Optional)</a> 
              <lightning-button name="Download PDF" value="Download PDF" label="Download PDF (Optional)" onclick="{!c.downloadPdf}" variant="brand" /> 
              </footer> -->
           <!-- Spinner Start -->
           <div class="spinnerHolder">
              <template if:true={showSpinner}>
                 <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading"> </lightning-spinner>
              </template>
           </div>
           <!-- Spinner End -->
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
     </div>
  </template>
```

JS:

```
    connectedCallback() {
  this.showSpinner = true;
  console.log('MVK Inside connected Callback');
  console.log('MVK Inside connected Callback this.closedFromPopup-->'+this.closedFromPopup);
  console.log('MVK Inside connected Callback this.closedFromPopup-->'+this.closedFromPopup);
    if(this.passedFromTable === false){
        this.showPdfPopupQuickAction = true;
    }
}


    closePdfPopup(event){
    console.log('MVK 5 Inside close quick action ');
    this.showPdfPopup = false;
    this.showPdfPopupQuickAction = false;
    this.closedFromPopup = true;
    this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
}
```

this.passedFromTable = false; //by default

Comment: Are you making `passedFromTable` true anywhere?

Comment: No, it's actually @api variable, when this component gets called from another parent, I pass it true, otherwise, it is false. Strange thing which I noticed when I open the console log and close it.. the button start working again, without any refresh. I wrote the code in connectedCallback expecting, that connectedCallback will get called everytime I click the quick action, and seem to be get called, yet it doesn't render.

Comment: I believe this is a LWC Quick action, which is already a modal, why do you need a modal code inside a modal?

Comment: when I didn't add the modal, the UI was looking weird (augmented at the end of the page)

Comment: do you have a screenshot of what happens when you click it again? Have you checked that `passedFromTable` is not null/undefined in this scenario (which might stop your template from rendering it)?